# Jenkins Git Plugin and Reference Repos?

Tags: git, jenkins

I set up a bare reference repo, and now Jenkins sometimes comes back with:

`error: object directory .git/objects does not exist; check .git/objects/info/alternates`

Why is it looking for .git/objects in the reference repo? It's even more funny because the file .git/objects/info/alternates has the exact path to the object dir of the reference repo.

I'm going to try putting in a symlink in the bare repo to point .git to itself, so the path above would work...

Answer (score 1):

the issue reported here

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-21434

i got the same problem in windows machine